# How to get the default loading icon of select2 JS

Tags: jquery

When any two charactes are entered on Employee Name Text Field , it shows a default loader of select2 js framework .

On Click of  a Button , can we show that default  Loader ??

I couldn't find the class or Id related to that loader .

Can you please help

This is my fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/XMAq2/1464/

```
<div id="maincontainer" class="clearfix">
    <!-- main content s-->
    <div id="contentwrapper">
      <div class="main_content">
        <div class="row-fluid">
          <div class="span6" id="employeeColumn">
            <div class="control-group">
              <label class="control-label">Employee Name: </label>
              <div class="controls">
                <input type="text" class="tags" id="select2_tags_id"/>                
              </div>
            </div>
            <!--control group -->
          </div>
          <!-- Employee Column -->

        </div>
        <!-- row-fluid -->
      </div>
      <!-- main_content -->
    </div>
    <!-- content wrapper -->
  </div>
  <!-- End of maincontainer -->


$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#select2_tags_id').select2({
        tokenSeparators: [','],
        tags: true,
        maximumSelectionSize: 10,
        minimumResultsForSearch: Infinity,
        multiple: true,
        dropdownCss: {
            display: 'none'
        }
    });


});
```

Comment: which button click event?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The style which is responsible for showing the icon is :

```
.select2-container-multi .select2-choices .select2-search-field input.select2-active {
    background: #fff url(select2-spinner.gif) no-repeat 100% !important;
}
```

I am not sure of the button you wanted to click, but idea is you need to add class "select2-active" on input when you click your button.
You may check the fiddle at "http://jsfiddle.net/XMAq2/1499/"

```
$( "#target" ).click(function() {
  alert('1');
    $('.select2-container-multi .select2-choices .select2-search-field input').addClass("select2-active");
});
     <a class="btn btn-primary" id="target"> Click me <a/>
```